# To obtain the current location

Tags: android, locationlistener

I am using the below code to obtain the location of a user

```
public class MainLocation extends Application implements LocationListener {
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude, longitude;
protected boolean gps_enabled, network_enabled;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.e("Location", "here");

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.e("Location", "" + location.getLatitude());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.e("Location Status", "" + provider + " " + status + " " + extras);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.e("Location", "Enabled");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.e("Location","Disabled"+provider);

}
```

}

but here the onLocationChanged function is never getting called, so i m not able fetch the location. So how can i get the location?
In the logcat, the info tab is showing the latitude and longitude under the title onLocationReceived".

This is the manifest,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.krijjj.loginapp" >
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".Location.MainLocation"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Track"
            android:label="Track" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Security.Lockscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.krijjj.loginapp.Second" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mapactivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Security.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mapactivity" >
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you have in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @Eenvincible i have added my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Play services location APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary) are preferred over the Android framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location awareness to your app.

You can find the example how to use it right [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

P.S. Don't forget to check if permissions granted on your device, if you added permissions into manifest file...

Comment: I used Google Play Services, but in that in the logcat "GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin." this is coming up.

Comment: What about your Gradle file?